# Show Library items in a ribbon when a document library is opened

Tags: ribbon

When a user navigates to a Document library the ribbon shows up, but by default the "Browse" section/button is selected in the button. Is there a way to change this selection to the "Library" option when a document library loads?

So when the document library page is loaded the user would see the "Library" selected in the ribbon and all the contents in the "Library" is shown in the ribbon.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a query string parameter InitialTabId. For example:

http://www.foo.com/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Library

To get Documents, the value would be Ribbon.Document (even though the tab is titled "Documents").

You can find other ids in the file (14 folder)/TEMPLATE/GLOBAL/XML/CMDUI.XML

Answer (score 1):

Ribbon.Library works fine but Ribbon.Document does not seem to work.

Using your link to illustrate-

When using Ribbon.Library as the default for a document library works as intended:

/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Library

But when using Ribbon.Document no tab is selected and the URL bar shows:

/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?

I tried setting it to Ribbon.Documents and the URL comes up fine:

/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?InitialTabId=Ribbon.Documents

But the tab is not selected because the tab ID is Ribbon.Document and not Ribbon.Documents

Comment: I could use some help with this if at all possible, this issue seems unique to our environment. I can set any tab on any ribbon as default for a document library or list EXCEPT the document tab in the library tools contextual group. Even Library, which is right beside it in the same contextual group works fine, but Ribbon.Document does not. The URL query string seems to be submitted when a link containing it is clicked, but sharepoint "appears" to be redirecting to /AllItems.aspx? and the query string has been stripped out besides the ? mark.